# Access js array in another js file

Tags: javascript, html

I fill my array in the checklistRequest.js and I want to access it in my Termine_1s.html file which contains js code. I can access it but when I want to iterate through it, it gives me only single digits instead of the strings.

How can I solve this?

**checklistRequest.js**

```
//Calls the checkbox values
function alertFunction()
{
    //Retrieve the object from storage
    var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('checkboxArray');

    console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));

    return retrievedObject;
}
```

**Termine_1s.html**

```
//Checks if title was checked already
var checklistRequest =  alertFunction();
var titleAccepted = true;

for (var a = 0; a < checklistRequest.length; a++)//Iterates through whole array
{
   if(title != checklistRequest[i] && titleAccepted == true)//Stops if false
   {
     titleAccepted = true;
   }
   else
   {
     titleAccepted = false;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to parse the object at some point.

Try:
return JSON.parse(retrievedObject);